# DialogFlow, text limitation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

i'm new to Google Cloud Platform and today i'm into DialogFlow!
Cheers!

I have a question about the "free" edition.

How many text can i send/recive to my Agent? 
There is any type of limitation about text? 
How many text i can send during a day, or during month?

The docs seems to be not precise about question, it just talk about audio for day and audio limits and i don't find anything online about that.
I want to know how many time can i ask and recive TEXT response from my Agent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [dialogflow doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/quotas), you can send **180 requests per minute** in the standard edition.

This does not mean you can send 3 requests per second, as the number of requests are counted per minute basis.

Other than that there is no boundation on requests.

Hope it helps.